# Inserting data with a SQL query and insert into command is taking forever

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, toad

I'm working on Oracle using Toad and I have a problem: I have a SQL query written on with syntax. And the query is quite long, but it returns the first 500 rows in 30 seconds, also export to Excel is quick and it takes 1 minute for all records.

But when I try to insert data with "insert into", the query doesn't manage to insert that data; I cancelled it after 20 minutes.

The table where I'm trying to insert into is empty.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

For now the quickest way for me to insert it is exporting whole data and then importing excel into table...But I'm not fan of that

Comment: Provide your code and data examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How many rows are involved in this operation? TOAD returns (and displays) first 500 rows, but - there might be *millions* of non-displayed rows. On the other hand, a 1-minute export suggests that number of rows isn't that large. Are there any triggers on table? Do you do that over database link? Are you sure you aren't waiting for table to be released (because it is locked)?

Comment: There are 360.000 rows and one tirgger that is enabled for inser/update/delete on table I'm not doing it over database link. I'm sure that table is not locked.

Comment: Hi , do you want to disable the trigger and see how much time the update is taking, this will narrow down the problem to the trigger.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 'table locked' includes uncommitted DML performed in another session, not just explicit table locks. Have you actually checked for locks in the data dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Guy thank you all for answers...The problem was that index was created wrong.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).